# Create a page filter with the last article of each category

Tags: views

My articles are grouped in 6 categories (created by taxonomy)

I need to output a view page that contains 6 sections each one displays in a block or div the latest article of the category it belongs.

I have a solution how to do that by creating 6 views for each category filtered desc and displaying the last article and a 7th view to hold all the 6 view blocks. The only thing I don't like it about this is if the editor enters a new category I need to manually update the view.

Is there a way to display the 6 cell grid with the categories as I mentioned before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure out based on Daniel Wehner clue. There is an obvious bug in the views handlers that has already been submited to the Views development team and got already fixed in the development snapshot.

**Step1. Fix the bug**
First you need to check your Apache's log and notice the line:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method views_handler_relationship_groupwise_max::view_aliased()  in ...\sites\all\modules\views\handlers\views_handler_relationship_groupwise_max.inc on line 200

If you get an Ajax error, you should see the error in a modal window.

Now you need to find out views_handler_relationship_groupwise_max.inc, and at line 200 replace the line:

```
$temp_view = $this->view_aliased();
```

with

```
$temp_view = $this->get_temporary_view();
```

Step2. **Create a taxonomy view of the categories**. Once you have the categories display you create a relationships of type: Representative node with the node title, sorted DESC and then add all the fields needed in the main view settings.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that's possible.

- Add a new taxonomy view
- Add a relationship: Representative node.
- There configure to sort by node created DESC.

That's it

Comment: Hello Daniel: I've created exactly as you said but after click ok in the relationships I got an ajax error: An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
HTTP Result Code: 200
Debugging information follows.
Path: /internal/admin/structure/views/ajax/config-item/topic/page/relationship/tid_representative
StatusText: OK
ResponseText: 
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined method views_handler_relationship_groupwise_max::view_aliased() in D:\www\internal\sites\all\modules\views\handlers\views_handler_relationship_groupwise_max.inc on line 200
Call Stack
#TimeMemoryFunctionLocation

Comment: I'm very interested in the "representative node" relationship myself. It looks like you need dev versions of views or apply a patch: http://drupal.org/node/1198200

Comment: maybe this can be done with a preprocess function, looping through an array of categories?